# Finding max element in first N elements of dynamic array

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm or data structure to find largest element by second parameter in first N elements of multiset in which I'll make many ,so I can't use segment tree.Any Ideas?

note:I have multiset of pairs.

Comment: Unlike the other close-voters, my issue with this question is not that it's too broad, but that it's unclear. What kinds of insertions and deletions do you need to perform on this "array"? What performance do those need to have? (If it's really an array, then insertions and deletions at arbitrary positions are O(size) anyway, so it seems like you might as well iterate over the first *N* elements directly to find the largest element.) It's clear that you have a bunch of requirements that you haven't mentioned; presumably they're obvious from context that we as readers lack.

Comment: Well I need logN complexity.And this array is a multiset sorted by other parameter.

Comment: When you say "array", what exactly do you mean? In most languages, "arrays" are a very specific thing that does *not* support logarithmic-time insertions and deletions.

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

You can use any balanced binary search tree implementation you are familiar with. Arguably the most well known are AVL tree, Red-black tree.

Usually binary search tree description mentions a **key** and **value** pair stored in tree node. The keys are ordered from left to right. Insert, delete and find operations work with O(log(n)) time complexity because tree is balanced. Balance is often supported by tree rotation.

In order to be able to find maximum value on a range of elements you have to store and maintain additional information in each tree node namely **maxValue** in the subtree of the node and **size** of the subtree. Define a recursive function for a node to find maximum value among the first N nodes of its subtree. If N is equal to **size** you will already have an answer in **maxValue** of current node. Otherwise call the function for left/right node if some elements are in threir subtrees.

```
F(node, N) = 
    if N == size[node] : maxValue[node]
    else if N <= size[leftChild[node]] : 
        F(leftChild[node], N)
    else if N == size[leftChild[node]] + 1 : 
        MAX(F(leftChild[node], N), value[node])
    else : 
        MAX(maxValue[leftChild[node]], 
            value[node], 
            F(rightChild[node], N - size[leftChild[node]] - 1)
```

If you are familiar with segment tree you will not encounter any problems with this implementation.

I may suggest you to use **Treap**. This is randomised binary tree. Because of the this randomised nature the tree always remains balances providing O(log(n)) time complexity for the basic operations. Treap DS has two basic operations **split** and **merge**, all other operations are implemented via their usage. An advatage of treap is that you don't have to deal with rotations.

EDIT: There is no way to maintain **maxKey**/**minKey** in each node explicitly O(log(n)).

Comment: @ruakh, you are right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ruakh, thank you for the important note!

Comment: does this still work after i edited question?because data should remain sorted by other parameter.

Comment: @luka25, in my answer it is assumed that data is sorted by their index. So index of the element is a **key** in binary search tree.